# Secure socket layer does not show for all my domains

Tags: ssl

I have bought SSL for my domain. when I enter https followed by domain.com it shows secure but www.domain.com or domain.com shows not secure. How can I solve this issue? Please help me.

Comment: Where is your domain hosted? And what is the page that is being accessed, are you hosting it on your own web server?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _https followed by domain.com_ and _domain.com_?

Comment: My domain is hosted on jelastic.com it's a glassfish 5.0 server.

Comment: It's hosted on jelastic.com using glassfish 5.0 , when I enter [https]://example.com it shows the secure logo with a lock but when I enter example.com or www.example.com it shows not secure. What I want is example.com or www.example.com everything goes to [https]://example.com so that it shows as secure